# Ruby - Using .dig to query values in a nested hash - returning blank

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to pull comments from reddit.com/r/programming and output the comments in the terminal. I pull the json from reddit and then parse it into a nested hash, but am having trouble querying the hash to pull the comments. Is using HASH.dig the correct approach?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments.json?sort=top&t=all&limit=10'
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
json = JSON.parse(response)
puts json.dig("children","data","body")
```

I'm looking output the comments one-by-one, but when I run the above, the output is blank. Here's a sample of the hash:

```
{"kind"=>"Listing", "data"=>{"modhash"=>"", "dist"=>10, "children"=>[{"kind"=>"t1", "data"=>{"subreddit_id"=>"t5_2tbbg", "approved_at_utc"=>nil, "edited"=>false, "mod_reason_by"=>nil, "banned_by"=>nil, "author_flair_type"=>"text", "removal_reason"=>nil, "link_id"=>"t3_8jwhvk", "author_flair_template_id"=>nil, "likes"=>nil, "replies"=>"", "user_reports"=>[], "saved"=>false, "id"=>"dz3b25e", "banned_at_utc"=>nil, "mod_reason_title"=>nil, "gilded"=>0, "archived"=>false, "report_reasons"=>nil, "author"=>"QueenCrownDown", "num_comments"=>1, "can_mod_post"=>false, "send_replies"=>true, "parent_id"=>"t3_8jwhvk", "score"=>1, "approved_by"=>nil, "over_18"=>false, "mod_note"=>nil, "collapsed"=>false, "body"=>"Any 25$ purchase or just Sunday Riley?! Def taking advantage of this I’ve wanted to try good genes for ages. ", "link_title"=>"[misc] Sunday Riley good genes 7 day sample with a $25 purchase at Sephora. Code:GOODGOOD",
```

Comment: Add to your post a sample of the `json` hash. Just a sample; and yes in general `.dig` is the right approach. Remember if your hash contain arrays you add their indices to `.dig`.

Comment: What result are you aiming for? What *exactly* do you mean by "pull in the comments"? If you're just asking "can I use `Hash#dig` for this?", then the answer is yes.

Comment: Or, you could use an [existing API wrapper](https://github.com/avinashbot/redd) if you're trying to do something "complicated"... (But since I don't know what you're doing, I can't advise on that!)

Comment: OK, looking at that sample JSON, your current attempt isn't going to work since the top level node in that JSON is `"data"`, not `"children"`. And you can't map directly from `"children"` to `"data"`, since it's actually an array. How about `json.dig("data", "children").map { |child| child.dig("data", "body") }` - is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Dig digs through arrays; just put in the index you need. `json.dig('data', 'children', 0, 'data', 'body')`.